# A good way to pass information javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an asp.net website, but I need to pass stuff to javascript to do stuff there. At the moment, I am doing things like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var userHasMicrositePhoto = '<%=hasMicrositePhoto%>';
</script>
```

But I've been told that putting lots of script tags in like this is bad, and also its annoying to have to keep writing Properties in my code behind.

What is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty much the ideal way to go IMO. If you have a lot of stuff like this, try putting it all in one `<script>`block. You could also use an array to reduce the code overhead, or have asp.net output a JSON encoded array with all the needed properties in it.

Depending on your architecture, you *could* consider fetching those properties through a separate Ajax request which would make the page body a bit cleaner, but it would be an extra request that can't be cached, so I would use this only in very extreme cases.

The same applies to embedding a separate `<script src=....>` it looks nicer in the generated markup, but needs another request to the server.

Answer (score 1):

I would use JSON when you're passing information to be used by javascript.
This may require you to reconsider how you're developing your website or application. I usually use it when the server is passing information via ajax but ajax isn't the only solution.

http://code.google.com/p/aspjson/

http://www.json.org/

I may not quite understand your question though so forgive me if I am totally off.

Answer (score 1):

The only alternatives would be

1. write a page that generates AJAX and have your JavaScript access
   that with XHR
2. write a page that generates JavaScript and have your
   HTML access that with a single script tag

I don't think either of those solutions are obviously superior to what you're doing now, except they could be used by other pages more easily, if that helps.